# Is it possible to overwrite an entry field with label in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a simple label and entry field that would:
1) Create a static label and clear the entry field after confirmation button click
2) Clear static label after reset button click

Is there any way to overwrite the entry field with a static label of the user input on the confirmation click instead of creating a new static label? And overwriting the static label with an empty entry field on the reset click?

Thank you for the help in advance.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame1 = Frame(root)
frame1.pack()


def reset():
     set_cname.destroy()
     cbtn['state'] = NORMAL

def confirm():
    global set_cname
    text1="Customer Name: " + entry1.get()
    set_cname = Label(frame1, text=text1)
    set_cname.grid(row=3, column=0, columnspan=1)
    entry1.delete(0, 'end')

    cbtn['state'] = DISABLED


cname = Label(frame1, text="Customer Name: ").grid(padx=5, pady=5, columnspan=2, sticky=W)
entry1 = Entry(frame1)
entry1.grid(row=0, column=2, padx=5)


cbtn = Button(frame1, text="Confirm", command=confirm, width=20)
cbtn.grid(row=1, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)

rbtn = Button(frame1, text="Reset Names", command=reset, width=20)
rbtn.grid(row=2, column=4, padx=5, pady=5)


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: use cbtn.text = 'something else' i hope this works in tkinter. works in kivy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can replace the Entry with a Label by first creating both and then using `pack()` to switch between them. The trick is to not let their different sizes affect the application layout, which can be accomplished by disabling size propagation.

In my example I create a new frame (`entry_frame`) with a fixed size and then disable size propagation (`.pack_propagate(False)`). Then I use this new frame to contain the Entry/Label. Im giving the `entry_frame` the bg color khaki to let you see exactly where it is.

I fiddled a bit with the column numbers also.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
frame1 = Frame(root)
frame1.pack()

def reset():
     text_label.pack_forget()
     entry1.pack()
     cbtn['state'] = NORMAL

def confirm():
    global set_cname
    entry1.pack_forget()
    text_label.config(text=entry1.get())
    text_label.pack(side='left')
    entry1.delete(0, 'end')
    cbtn['state'] = DISABLED

cname = Label(frame1, text="Customer Name: ")
cname.grid(row=0, column=0, padx=5, pady=5, sticky=W)

entry_frame = Frame(frame1, width=130, height=20, bg='khaki')
entry_frame.grid(row=0, column=1, padx=5, pady=5, sticky='nsew')
entry_frame.pack_propagate(False)   # Disable size propagation
entry1 = Entry(entry_frame)         # Customer name entry
entry1.pack()
text_label = Label(entry_frame)     # Label to hold customer name

cbtn = Button(frame1, text="Confirm", command=confirm, width=20)
cbtn.grid(row=1, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

rbtn = Button(frame1, text="Reset Names", command=reset, width=20)
rbtn.grid(row=2, column=2, padx=5, pady=5)

root.mainloop()
```

Be aware that this solution will be sensitive to font size changes.